# How is the daily/month compound interest calculated?

Tags: finance

I am trying to work out how this website is calculates the daily and month compound interest. The website is taking the profit/loss from the broker for each trade and calculating the overall % gain. The it calculates the compound.

I am not sure how many days it is using for its calculation. There are 22 trades on the chart.

Here is the link to the website https://www.myfxbook.com/portfolio/forex-pro-island/5359331

[image]

Comment: I think the lone *Close Vote* is premature, considering that *Keith Power* is a new contributor.

Comment: You can try referring to the [Wikipedia page on *Time series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), @KeithPower.